# Custom Elasticsearch Query in Kibana

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, kibana-4

Is it possible to use a custom Elasticsearch query in Kibana? For example, I have a query that does several aggregations across different types, and I would like to setup a visualization for it. The Kibana UI only allows - AFAIK - relatively simple queries. This would be with the latest versions of ES (2.2.0) and Kibana (4.1.1).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think Kibana 4.1 only supports queries in the form of [Simple Query String Queries](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-simple-query-string-query.html). But -- and this was news to me -- it looks like [Kibana 4.4 supports custom queries](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/4.4/discover.html).